# Angular displaying flash message after failed login

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, authentication

I am building an angular application in Angular 9 and i am trying to display a flash message when the login fails, i don't understand what i am missing.

This is the LoginComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  state;
  message: any;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authenticationService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.state = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
    if(authenticationService.isLoggedIn()){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('');
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: '',
      userpass: ''
    });
  }

  onSubmit(credentials){
    this.authenticationService.login(credentials).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      if(res.token != null){
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      } else {
        console.log("Wrong email or password");
        this.message = "Wrong email or password";
      }
    });
  }

}
```

This is the LoginComponent html:

```
<div class="hero is-large is-success" align="center">
    <div class="hero-head">
        <h2 class="title">Login</h2>
        <div *ngIf="message != null" class="notification">
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
        </div>

        <form class="is-centered" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm.value)">
            <div class="container">
                <input class="form-control input is-rounded is-dark" type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="email"/><br>
                <input class="form-control input is-rounded is-dark" type="password" formControlName="userpass" placeholder="password"/><br>
                <input type="submit" class="button is-rounded is-dark" value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-body">

    </div>
</div>
```

The AuthenticationService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Appdata } from '../appdata';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  authUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.authUrl = Appdata.url + "/auth";
  }

  login(credentials) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.authUrl+'/login', credentials).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
      if(res.token != null){
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login', { state: res.status }]);
      }
    });
  }

  register(user) {
    return this.http.post<any>(Appdata.url+'/register', user).subscribe((res: any) =>{
      if(res.redirect != null){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/register', { state: res.status }]);
      }
    });
  }

  unregister(credentials) {
    return this.http.post<any>(Appdata.url+'/unregister', credentials).subscribe((res: any) => {
      if(res.redirect != null){
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/unregister', { state: res.status }]);
      }
    });
  }

  logout(){
    if(this.isLoggedIn()){
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }
  }

  isLoggedIn(){
    return localStorage.getItem('token') != null;
  }

}
```

One thing to notice is that when the 401 status is reached it goes to the correct url (which is: http://localhost:4200/login;state=401) but it doesn't log the message and it doesn't display the message in the html page.

I have already tried using angular2-flash-messages and ng-flash-messages module but they don't seem to do the job.

Comment: You are just catching an error with extra steps. When the login fails, you change the URL, then you attempt to read the URL in order to know if you have to display a message. Why not display the message directly after the login fails in `authenticationService`?

Comment: wouldn't that reduce the scalbility of the code? anyway how should i do that? i am new to Angular (3 days) and i don't know much of it.

Comment: Imagine that, in order to catch an error, you change the URL hash, then you read the URL hash, and if there is a specific word in it, change the background of the site to red, then test the color of the background, if it is red then make an image spin, then test if the image is spinning, and if the image is spinning, it means the background is red, therefore the URL has a specific word, therefore the login failed :) No, going straight to the point doesn't reduce the scalability! Instead of changing the URL, just display your error message.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, how should i do it? i mean in the practical way i would in the AuthenticationService when the response says that the login is failed i have to find a way of flashing the message so what would you suggest to achive this? (i update the question with the AuthenticationService class so you can see the code and correct me).

Comment: From your component, you can subscribe to the observable returned by the login method : `this.authenticationService.login(credentials).subscribe( res => { 
 .. });` so in the component you'll have your answer directly, you can display the alert message.

Comment: So i have updated the code and it works but are you sure this doen't reduce the scalability of the code? cause i thought that the method to store the token had to go in the AuthenticationService could please take a look at the code and see if i did what you meant correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Reduce the scalability", but why would it? That's the way to go. Did my suggestion work?

Comment: yes it totally did thanks, what i mean by saying "Reduce the scalability" is that making the LoginComponent store the token creates a dipendency to the AuthenticationService (what i mean is that the AuthenticationService doesn't store the token but relies on the LoginComponent to do that) and i thought that could be unsafe (i am planning to use this code for multiple projects).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're always subscribing and you're only getting the "next" handler AKA the handler that will trigger when things go well.

Essentially what you want to do is add the error function to do extra handling over there since the Angular HTTP client sends the HTTP error codes over that function.

Your typescript component could look something like the following:

```js
@Component({...})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  message : string = ''

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  
  onSubmit() {
    this.authenticationService.login(credentials)
      .subscribe(
         (res: any) => {
           localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
           this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
         }, 
         (error: any) => {
           // if your server responds with a 4XX or 5XX status code
           // this error handler will be called.
           // here you can have more logic than this
           this.message = 'Invalid username or password'
         }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

And then make sure you're returning **the Observable** and **NOT** the subscription:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
    this.authUrl = Appdata.url + "/auth";
  }

  login(credentials): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.authUrl+'/login', credentials)
  }
}
```

This should result in you seeing the errors on your `(error: any) => {...}` function